# PXSSH Connection fails sometimes randomly after upgrading to Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect, pxssh

I am trying to create a ssh session using pexpect.pxssh as follows:

```
from pexpect import pxssh
connection = pxssh.pxssh()
connection.login('localhost', username, password, port=port, check_local_ip=False)
"""
Fails with the following error
pexpect.pxssh.ExceptionPxssh: Could not establish connection to host
"""
```

Also I create two sessions one after the other, the first session connects without a problem but the second session fails to connect with the same code. Also, sometimes the code works properly and is able to connect both times. I have also added retries just to be sure that it's not a random event.

Another thing to note is that this code runs without a problem with Python 2 but with Python 3 this happens. I couldn't find any difference in the connection mechanism b/w Python2 and Python3. Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT: After adding logging as per comment:

***2021-06-25 10:49:37 INFO - Attempting to connect to device on port 10022.

Connecting to USB device...

Jun 25 10:49:37  tcprelay[203] : Created thread to connect [::1]:10022->[::1]:58316<12> to unix:0<15>

user@localhost's password: xxxxx

Jun 25 10:49:37  tcprelay[203] : Exiting thread to connect [::1]:10022->[::1]:58316 to unix:0***

***Connecting to USB device...

Jun 25 10:49:38  tcprelay[203] : Created thread to connect [::1]:10022->[::1]:58317<12> to unix:0<15>

user@localhost's password: xxxxx

Jun 25 10:49:39  tcprelay[203] : Exiting thread to connect [::1]:10022->[::1]:58316 to unix:0***

The code retries 2 times and then fails.
Note: I am adding a port offset of 10000 using tcprelay

EDIT:

Sorry I was not logging the error properly.

```
2021-06-25 15:45:34 - ERROR - Failed to connect. Retrying...
2021-06-25 15:45:34 - ERROR - End Of File (EOF). Empty string style platform.
<pexpect.pxssh.pxssh object at 0x127feb0a0>
command: /usr/bin/ssh
args: ['/usr/bin/ssh', '-q', '-oNoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost=yes', '-p', 'xxxxx', '-l', 'xxxxx', 'localhost']
buffer (last 100 chars): b''
before (last 100 chars): b' \r\n'
after: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: True
pid: 30020
child_fd: 26
closed: False
timeout: 60
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
logfile: <_io.BufferedWriter name='<stdout>'>
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile(b'(?i)are you sure you want to continue connecting')
    1: re.compile(b'[#$]')
    2: re.compile(b'(?i)(?:password:)|(?:passphrase for key)')
    3: re.compile(b'(?i)permission denied')
    4: re.compile(b'(?i)terminal type')
    5: TIMEOUT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/helpers/utilities.py", line 590, in try_connect_ssh
    connection.make_connection(ipaddress=ipaddress, user=user,
  File "/src/transport/myssh.py", line 26, in make_connection
    self.ssh_process.login(ipaddress, user, password, port=port, sync_multiplier=5, check_local_ip=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pexpect/pxssh.py", line 418, in login
    i = self.expect(session_regex_array)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 343, in expect
    return self.expect_list(compiled_pattern_list,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 372, in expect_list
    return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 179, in expect_loop
    return self.eof(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 122, in eof
    raise exc
pexpect.exceptions.EOF: End Of File (EOF). Empty string style platform.
<pexpect.pxssh.pxssh object at 0x127feb0a0>
```

EDIT:

- Using macOS Mojave
- pExpect 3.8.0
- Device asks for password but after password is sent the connection returns EOF

Comment: Try adding some debug. E.g. `connection = pxssh.pxssh(encoding='utf8',logfile = sys.stdout)`.  Trap the exception and print out the state of the connection: `try:... ;except ...: print(str(connection))`

Comment: @meuh Thanks for the reply. I have added the logs as per the pxssh stdout logger although there seems to be no apparent error. the code keeps trying to reconnect regardless.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see what might be the problem. As you can see, the remote seems to send back `" \r\n`` (in `before (last 100 chars): b' \r\n'`) and then closes the connection (get EOF).

Comment: @meuh Sorry for the late update. One more thing I wanted to mention is that the password prompt shows up but after the password is sent the device sends EOF.

Comment: The principal difference between python 2 and 3 was the support of unicode and so the distinction between strings and bytes. Usually, however, this results in obvious exceptions due to encoding, which you do not have. I can only suggest you replace pxssh by the lower level `pexpect.spawn()` which is just as easy to use, and will allow you to more easily see what is being sent and returned. If you have problems with this new pexpect, start a new post.

Comment: @meuh thanks for the suggestion. The problem happens with pexpect too. I have created another post for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68386639/pexpect-connection-receives-eof-after-password-prompt